# Converter formato da data sql server

Tags: sql-server

Bom, estou precisando converter a data no sql server para dd/mm/yyyy preciso de um update ou algo que possa me ajudar. Imagem da coluna da tabela abaixo, como está agora:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que fique **03-10-2016** por exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto é somente o formato de exibição padrão dentro do banco, a informação da data em si está correta e não tem o que alterar.
Caso queira retornar a data formatada do jeito mencionado, você vai precisar fazer algo desse tipo

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE(),105)`

O último parâmetro é que determina como virá a formatação, para mais detalhes de quais números são possíveis: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar usar:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)
```

Existem outras opções em: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp